# file not found (ajax)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code:

```
svg = $("#rsr").svg({ loadURL: '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/svg_curv.svg")', onLoad: svgLoaded });
```

This code load svg file (Jquery SVG plugin). On local web server all works fine. But in production web server I get the following error: `404 Not Found`.
The file is exist on server:
[image]

Also, it's not found if I open the file via browser (`mysite.com/content/images/svg_curv.svg`), but other files in the `images` folder is found.

Where is a problem?
Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: Is your local as well as remote web-server windows-server based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know much about your enviroment. but you need to add/allow  svg **MIME** Type on your webserver

[Allow MIME TYPE in IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true)

[Add New MIME Type](http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/IIS/newmime/)